# How to filter data in categories using django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have been working on a django project very similar to hoop in which a user can search for friends using an snapchat profile. Hoop filters the users by region for example before using the app, the  user has to select the region the user is right now to later show that profile for the people searching friends in that region, also the app asks the user to select the region where the user wants to search for new friends.

I want to do the same filtering but instead of filtering the region, I want to filter by categories. Currently my code just shows the profiles to all the users but I have started to create 2 categories which are "action" and "sports" but I don't know how to process that filtering.

models

```
CATEGORY_CHOICES = (
    ('action', 'action'),
    ('sports', 'sports'),
)

class Mates(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='usermates', unique=True)
    categories = models.CharField(choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES, default="choose...", max_length=10)
    req_bio = models.CharField(max_length=400)
    req_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='requestmates_pics', null=True, blank=True, default=False)
```

views.py

```
def matesmain(request):
    contents = Mates.objects.all()
    context = {
        'contents': contents,
        'form_mates': MatesForm(),
    }
    print("nice3")
    return render(request, 'mates.html', context)

def mates(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form_mates = MatesForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form_mates.is_valid():
            instance = form_mates.save(commit=False)
            instance.user = request.user
            instance.save()
            return redirect('mates-main')
            print('succesfully uploded')

    else:
        form_mates = MatesForm()
        print('didnt upload')
    return redirect('mates-main')
```

forms.py

```
class MatesForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Mates
        fields = ('req_bio', 'req_image',)
        exclude = ['user']
```

mates.html (here is the form of the html)

```
{% for content in contents %}
    {% if not content.user == user %}
        <div class="mates-grid">
            <div class="mates-grid-1">
                <div class="mates-item">
                    <form action="{% url 'mates' %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <div class="form-item-img">
                            <input type="file" name="req_image" accept="image/*" id="id_req_image">
                         </div>
                         <div class="form-item-bio">
                             <input type="text" name="req_bio" maxlength="400" required="" id="id_req_bio">
                         </div>
                         <div class="form-item-button">
                             <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                         </div>
                     </form>
                 </div>                             
             </div>
         </div>
         {% endif %}
     {% endfor %}
```

Comment: does this work, **`Mates.objects.filter(categories='action')`**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using numbers for your choices, you would do this:

```
def matesmain(request):
    action = Mates.objects.filter(categories='action')
    sports = Mates.objects.filter(categories='sports')
    
    context = {
        'action' : action,
        'sports' : sports,
        
    }
    
    return render(request, 'mates.html', context)
```

this way if you use the action context you get the all the user related to action category and so on for the sports category.

Comment: Yess cause you need only the user of the particular category not all of it.

Comment: How will the code look like on the mates view? because I need to add 2 questions there like "what category does your profile belong" and "what are you searching for"

Comment: i dont get your question properly. Could you be more specify and detailed?

Comment: yes! well I mean that mates view is for uploading the user's profile right? there should alse be 2 questions(which arent in my code yet) in which the user has to answer to what category the user's profile belongs to and what category is the user searching for, finally in both questions the user has to select between action and sports. Was that clear?

Comment: I will add the html to the question

Comment: basically you want a form where the user can select which category to choose. If that is  the case just add the categories in your MateForm fields. This will create a dropdown list where the user can choose the category he wants